# What are the requirements for the conveyor for the Large Cargo Container in Space Engineers

Tags: space-engineers

I recently built a miner in survival mode of Space Engineers got it fully hooked up and running aside from one thing and that is the inventory of the Large Cargo Container will not push out it's cargo from the ejectors. I've made sure to connect it properly with a conveyor, I can even move cargo from it to the ejector from a terminal anywhere on the ship. But it will not send a push request for the cargo it's holding.

Does anyone know how to properly setup a Large Cargo Container and make it work with a conveyor system including ejectors?

Comment: You'll find that it is much more time-efficient to use connectors rather than ejectors if you are trying to move ore from your mining ship to your refinery ship/station. It can be tricky to line up the connectors while docking, but once docked, the contents of your miner's cargo bay will move as fast as you can drag/drop into the containers on the refinery ship/station. Ejecting a full large cargo container worth of stuff can take minutes in comparison. The connectors need to be powered and set to use the conveyor system, of course.

Comment: @GodEmperorDune Thanks a lot for the tip! I started on the map Asteroids where you get a pre-attached connector so I guess I'll have to switch to that one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My first gravity collector ship used a grid of 9 ejectors that i aimed in the general direction of a funnel with collector under gravity; perhaps slow but fun. I also stuck a ejector on either side of the drill in a single drill ship when gravity collecting; was like snorkeling rocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out you have to toggle the collect button in the control panel on the ejectors for it to pull the resources from the Large Cargo Container.

Comment: Ahh, Tom, that would of been better posted as a comment. If @GodEmperorDune has answered your question, ask them to post it as an answer. If not, flag it for closure.

Comment: @FinnRayment While GodEmperorDune has given me quite the useful alternative. My own conclusion was the direct answer. I'd gladly give GodEmperor credit for his insight but I thought I'd add in my findings for future reference should anyone come across the same situation as me. For next time I will definitely keep it in mind.

Comment: Ah, my fault sorry. Even though you wrote *"you **also**"*, it was still **an answer**. I interpreted it as **an addon** to the question. Again, my bad. Good luck and drift safely! :P

Comment: I can see why it might have seen as an addon to the question. I'll edit it out! Thanks for the feedback.